# Sort by date between two signified rows

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, identity-column

I am trying to make a VBA code autosort data based on the data in the N column but I am stuck up on how to make it sort between two rows where the range may change.  In other works I have two columns,

1) Ensign 88

2) Precision 560

The number of rows between them will allways be changeing (adding and deleting), but I dont want it to sort the rows outside those two title rows.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to update your question attaching a print screen of your Sheet with these above columns and sample data?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) will help ... to help you find the last row for the column(s) you want to sort on.

Comment: `Way 1:` Name your range and sort that named range? Whenever you add more rows, the named range will automatically adjust. `Way 2:` Use .FIND to find "Ensign 88" and "Precision 560" and then construct your range